# Importing Haskell Libraries like System.Random

Tags: haskell, random, import, module, cabal

So I've been searching and searching on how to fix this issue and I've had no luck finding out how.

First of all I want to import System.Random into my Haskell program.

```
import System.Random
```

Unfortunately it isn't that easy... When I execute the program in ghci this is what it returns:

```
Could not find module `System.Random'
Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
```

So obviously I do what it says... Same issue except I see what package database it is using:

```
Using binary package database: /usr/local/Cellar/ghc/7.6.3/lib/ghc-7.6.3/package.conf.d/package.cache
```

I go to that directory and surprise surprise... My random packages isn't there. I go to my .cabal/packages and copy my random-1.0.1.1 file to the

```
/usr/local/Cellar/ghc/7.6.3/lib/ghc-7.6.3/
```

directory where the other packages are. I run the program again and still get the same error. I realize when I look in the ghc-7.6.3/package.conf.d, that there is no file pointing towards the random file within the the lib.

What do I do??

I am desperate. How do I install packages!!!

---

Also I've tried cabal install but I get a huge error:

```
Failed to install random-1.0.1.1
Last 10 lines of the build log ( /Users/mikeecb/.cabal/logs/random-1.0.1.1.log ):
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
random-1.0.1.1 failed during the configure step. The exception was:
user error (In file included from
/usr/local/Cellar/ghc/7.6.3/lib/ghc-7.6.3/include/Rts.h:30,

from
/var/folders/lw/mwgzrbns2j10_p75xtydr9_r0000gn/T/ghc3806_0/ghc3806_0.c:1:0:


/usr/local/Cellar/ghc/7.6.3/lib/ghc-7.6.3/include/Stg.h:65:18:
error: math.h: No such file or directory
In file included from
/usr/local/Cellar/ghc/7.6.3/lib/ghc-7.6.3/include/Rts.h:32,

from
/var/folders/lw/mwgzrbns2j10_p75xtydr9_r0000gn/T/ghc3806_0/ghc3806_0.c:1:0:


/usr/local/Cellar/ghc/7.6.3/lib/ghc-7.6.3/include/HsFFI.h:30:20:
error: stdint.h: No such file or directory

In file included from
/var/folders/lw/mwgzrbns2j10_p75xtydr9_r0000gn/T/ghc3806_0/ghc3806_0.c:1:0:


/usr/local/Cellar/ghc/7.6.3/lib/ghc-7.6.3/include/Rts.h:190:20:
error: stdlib.h: No such file or directory
In file included from
/usr/local/Cellar/ghc/7.6.3/lib/ghc-7.6.3/include/Rts.h:227,

from
/var/folders/lw/mwgzrbns2j10_p75xtydr9_r0000gn/T/ghc3806_0/ghc3806_0.c:1:0:


/usr/local/Cellar/ghc/7.6.3/lib/ghc-7.6.3/include/rts/Flags.h:17:19:
error: stdio.h: No such file or directory
In file included from
/usr/local/Cellar/ghc/7.6.3/lib/ghc-7.6.3/include/Rts.h:227,

from
/var/folders/lw/mwgzrbns2j10_p75xtydr9_r0000gn/T/ghc3806_0/ghc3806_0.c:1:0:


/usr/local/Cellar/ghc/7.6.3/lib/ghc-7.6.3/include/rts/Flags.h:22:0:
error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘FILE’

/usr/local/Cellar/ghc/7.6.3/lib/ghc-7.6.3/include/rts/Flags.h:188:0:
error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘FILE’
In file included from
/usr/local/Cellar/ghc/7.6.3/lib/ghc-7.6.3/include/Rts.h:234,

from
/var/folders/lw/mwgzrbns2j10_p75xtydr9_r0000gn/T/ghc3806_0/ghc3806_0.c:1:0:


/usr/local/Cellar/ghc/7.6.3/lib/ghc-7.6.3/include/rts/Threads.h:19:23:
error: sys/types.h: No such file or directory
In file included from
/usr/local/Cellar/ghc/7.6.3/lib/ghc-7.6.3/include/Rts.h:234,

from
/var/folders/lw/mwgzrbns2j10_p75xtydr9_r0000gn/T/ghc3806_0/ghc3806_0.c:1:0:


/usr/local/Cellar/ghc/7.6.3/lib/ghc-7.6.3/include/rts/Threads.h:49:0:
error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘forkProcess’
)
```

Comment: You shouldn't need to copy files around manually, the compiler won't properly find them that way anyway.  Did you install `random` with the haskell platform or did you use `cabal install`?

Comment: I used cabal install random

Comment: how did you install `ghc` and `cabal`?  What OS are you running?

Comment: Running OS X 10.9.1. I installed it using Homebrew

Comment: I don't have much experience with OSX.  If you didn't install from the [Haskell Platform installer](http://www.haskell.org/platform/mac.html), I would recommend uninstalling and trying it this way.  It'll get pretty much everything set up for you instead of having to install components separately, and comes with a number of popular libraries, including `random`.  It's what I use on Windows and Ubuntu if I'm installing GHC.  Sorry I can't be any more help, I just don't have an OSX to play with.

Comment: Well that was silly but its working now and so many more packages are included! Thank you so much

Comment: Glad you got it working!  It can be a bit of a hassle to get set up the first time (and eventually you'll discover the fun that is "cabal hell"), but it isn't too bad after you get started.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it appears that uninstalling and then reinstalling GHC from the [Haskell Platform](http://www.haskell.org/platform/mac.html) for Mac OSX got it working properly.